# Get users email id

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the user's email id from my app automatically.. instead of asking the user to register with his email id or something like that....

I want to know who all bought my app, and want their email-id's to send them more info via mail..

thanks in advance...

Comment: If someone wants more info, they'll happily sign up for it.  Don't be a spammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, users should always be given the choice to "opt-in" and register that level of detail to receive additional information if they so desire. Harvesting the email address without them knowing about it would not be a good idea.

Comment: Hmmm... right now i ask for the email id, and i also have a feature where they can email me the change requests directly from my app, but people dont subscribe or send emails.. and put their change requests in Android Market as comments... Just want to stop it somehow and have a direct contact with the customer....

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no such facility. You should provide users with a Register facility to be informed about the updates. I think people will willingly register as they are paying for the app.

Comment: Hmmm.. will show them a popup after the user updates and runs the app (only once, first run after update).. and will let u guys know the response